# In Lego Indiana Jones, how do I free play with other characters in a useful fashion?

Tags: lego-indiana-jones

I've bought a bunch of the unlockable characters, including the Bazooka Trooper.  So now I want to go back and explode some silver!  The problem I'm having is, having done that, I can't seem to select the team I want to.  I get one choice of character; and when I choose them, they replace Indy.  Which means I'm stuck at the first whip swing.  I'm pretty sure most of the other characters used in story mode are required to complete the level, as well.

So, how do I add / replace other characters instead of Indy, to create a team that can actually complete the level?

Note: This is the Xbox 360 version, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried holding Y?  I've not played Indiana Jones, but in Batman 2 you can choose from *any* of the unlocked characters in free play by holding Y and navigating the full menu.  The team they choose is just what you cycle through with the triggers.

Comment: @agent86 Unfortunately you can't do that in the earlier games.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get one choice of character, but as you may have noticed, the CPU picked a set of other characters to join you. They don't follow you around in the world; instead you swap between them in real-time using the shoulder buttons. So you can start as X and turn into Y to get past Y's obstacle, then swap back and continue on as X.

The team that the CPU picks will be composed of random characters that together have all the abilities in the game (unless you have yet to unlock/buy any characters with that ability). Therefore, you are certain to have all the tools to complete the level and get all the loot.

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't have this game. But I do have other Lego games, and this is how they work.</sub>